# AngularJS ui-Router Nested Views throwing error: No Such State

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I'm trying to set up a fairly complex page design with multiple ui-views. I've extracted it to a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/DwridY).

I have a main ui-view with several possible templates being loaded. Several of these templates have multiple ui-views of their own, for example:

```
<h1>Workflows</h1>
<div class="well">
    <div ui-view="workflow.list"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="well">
    <div ui-view="workflow.details"></div>
 </div>
```

The angular config lists the states like this:

```
  .state('tasks', {
    url: "/tasks",
    views: {
      "mainView": {
        templateUrl: "tasks.html",
        controller: "TaskController"
      }
    }
  })      
  .state("task.list", {
    url: "/taskList",
    views: {
      "task.list": {templateUrl: "task.list.html"},
    }
  })  
  .state("workflow", {
    url: "/workflows",
    views: {
      "mainView": {
        templateUrl: "workflow.html",
        controller: "WorkflowController"
      }
    }
  })
  .state("workflow.list", {
    url: "/workflowsList",
    views: {
      "workflow.list": {templateUrl: "workflow.list.html"},
      "workflow.details": {templateUrl: "workflow.details.html"}
    }
  });
```

The problem is that it works with the workflow state and it's sub-views  but not the task state.

When I call:

```
function TaskController($scope, $state) {
   $state.transitionTo("task.list");
}
```

I get thrown an error:

> No such state 'task.list'.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've now updated the Plunker to a fully working version, and expanded it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general - if there is a `.` *(dot)* in the state name - UI-Router expects that it means:

- before last *dot* - parent name *(parents if more dots)*
- after last dot - current state name

so, what we are experiencing above with **`"task.list"`** is either

- missing state `"task"` or
- declaration `"tasks.list"` *(the parent will be existing "tasks" instead of "task")*

Here is the [updated and working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u54WW66Le9gDlqgLMuBH?p=preview), where I decided to use tasks as parent:

```
.state('tasks', {
    url: "/tasks",
    views: {
      "mainView": {
        templateUrl: "tasks.html",
        controller: "TaskController"
      }
    }
})      
//.state("task.list", {
.state("tasks.list", { // here we inherit from "tasks" not "task"
    url: "/taskList",
    views: {
      "task.list": {templateUrl: "task.list.html"},
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Radim, I understand this now.

Comment: Great to see that, sir! Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)

Comment: missing state 'task' was the key. Thank you!